# Как изменить цвет фона активной кнопки у Material SegmentedButton?

Tags: android, android-style, styled-components

Почему-то colorContainer меняет цвет фона для обоих состояний - отмечено и не отмечено. А как для отмеченного состояния выбрать другой цвет?

```
<style name="SegmentedButtonOverlay" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton">
        <item name="colorContainer">#00000000</item>
        <item name="colorOnContainer">@color/md_theme_dark_onPrimaryContainer</item>
    </style>
```

[Тут](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md) про это ничего не сказано, ну или я не вижу